# How to find the corners in a skeleton image using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I have prepossessed and created skeleton image from an input image. But i couldn't figure out perfect solution for finding corners. I've tried using hough transform to find the lines and then calculate intersection. but it doesn't work well with given image as the lines are not perfect straight lines.

Any suggestions please

[image: skeleton image]

Comment: Have you tried [`detectHarrisFeatures`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectharrisfeatures.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Some simple solution:

You can check each point of the graph for corner candidate:
1. Gather all points that are pretty close to this (in some neighborhood of the tested point)
2. Find center of mass for these points
3. Check the distance from the tested point to the center of mass - if distance is big, the point is candidate for corner

For each connected group of candidates select one and it will be the corner.

If the shape of your skeleton is not very complex, you'll get your corners.

If you need more precise result, you can approximate each neighborhood of points with a line using polyfit function and then calculate maximum deviation of points from this line. If deviation is big - it's a corner.